# Как решить проблему "You have a usable connection already"?

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2017

Столкнулся с проблемой заполнения элемента Windows Forms - DataGridView данными из базы данных MySQL. Мне необходимо привязать столбцы таблицы из базы к DataGrinView. 
Перед этим заданием я ознакомился с [этими](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/bind-wf-controls-with-the-bindingsource) и [этими](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/visual-studio/en/visual-studio-install.html) материалами.
Работаю в Microsoft Visual Studio 2017, версия всего софта MySQL - последняя, скачана [отсюда](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/), сам сервер запущен на *localhost* Во время создания нового SQL подключения в Visual Studio вылетает ошибка "You have a usable connection already". Подскажите пожалуйста, как её решить.
Видел [этот топик](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38862525/mysql-visual-studio-2015-you-have-a-usable-connection-already), однако это решение не помогло.

### Как я пытался решить проблему

- переустанавливал отдельные программы из вышеупомянутого инсталятора по очереди
- переустанавливал софт всем паком
- устанавливал разные версии вышеупомянутой сборки
- устанавливал не всё сразу, а по-одиночные установщики [отсюда](https://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/windows/)
- создавал новую базу данных
- запускал демона mysqd с пропуском таблиц верификации откуда пришёл коннект `mysqld --skip-grant-tables`
- создавал новые таблицы, базы данных, профили пользователей, а так же
  давал им различные уровни прав
- чистил регистры и кэши CCleaner'ом в промежутках между
  переустановками
- менял, сбрасывал пароли пользователей как через MySQL Workbench, так и через таблицы с данными пользователей сервера БД

Comment: не надо слов, вы же проблему в коде ищете? вот и покажите ваш код

Comment: ну и пробуйте гуглить, например [раз](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39001594/you-have-a-usable-connection-already-error-in-visual-studio-2015-adding-data-s), [два](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38862525/mysql-visual-studio-2015-you-have-a-usable-connection-already?rq=1)

Comment: @tym, с чего вы взяли, что проблема в коде? Которого нет в принципе,  исключая Дефолтный,  сгенрированный при создании проекта. Прочитайте описание вопроса внимательно,  там я указал, что такие манипуляции уже были проведены безрезультатно

Comment: Я решил, что проблема в коде, так как если у вас нет кода, то говорить не о чем по сути. Мы здесь ведь проблемы в коде и обсуждаем, верно? Иначе это просто какой то теоретический вопрос, который к практике отношения не имеет. Ознакомьтесь пожста с тем, [как задавать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) и как [привести пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), так как если кто то захочет вам помочь, сйечас он не сможет это сделать, тк у вас нет в вопросе никакой информации по которой можно было бы воспроизвести вашу проблему.

Comment: Я вам пишу, так как у меня тоже VS2017 (пишу на asp.net core 2.1) + mariadb и оно работает, также подключаюсь к mariadb из VSCode (через расширение) - работает, также подключаюсь к mariadb через workbench - работает, на проде у меня оч старая версия mysql под линуксом - подключение тоже работает. Это не совсем то же, что у вас, но вашу проблему я не смог воспроизвести